# Saving an Array as Textfile in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, visual-studio, text-files

I am trying to save an array (declared double) with `4x1` dimension as text file `(.txt)`. After assigning values, I converted the array into string by using `".ToString"`.

```
Dim flowl = New Double() {129.5, 55.33, 0, 12.65}
Dim flowt As String = flowl.ToString
```

Then using `".WriteAllText"` I tried to save this "`flowt`" string array as text file. But in text file it is saving "`system.double[]`". Could anyone suggest me how I can avoid this? Or is there any other better way to save an array as text file?

Thank you in advance.......

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable is just at first a data structure rather than a value, outputting to string only returns the object.

If you want exactly the same formatting, try

```
        '' some way to tell the index because there seems to be no .Index
    Dim item_no As Integer = 0
    '' start the output
        Dim out As String = "{";    
    ''   iterate through data in the array!!
        For Each item As Double In flowl    
           out += item
    ''   get next index (prematurely)
           item_no += 1                    
    ''   before actually getting next item, check if index now equals length
           If item_no = flowl.Length Then  
    ''   output close bracket
              out += "}"    
           Else
              out += " ,"    '' output delimiter
           End If
        Next '' end of for
```

You could fix it up yourself. Also, the As statement is not always needed unless you need to specifically cast something or communicate type.